# How to fill the gap created after thresholding the image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I'm trying to segment the hand out of the image using OpenCV python. One of the images contains a ring on one of the fingers as shown here

[image: 1]

After thresholding I get this result:

[image: 2]

How can I reconnect the finger after thresholding?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791949/how-to-fix-the-colors-of-the-image-to-get-a-better-thresholding-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how you thresholded your image, but if we use it and morphological closing we can close some gaps:

```
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (31, 31)))
```

[image: Symmetrical closing]

One problem you can notice is it closes in all directions. If you know there are more likely gaps in vertical direction you can change the structuring element accordingly:

```
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 31)))
```

[image: Asymmetrical closing]

Comment: follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791949/how-to-fix-the-colors-of-the-image-to-get-a-better-thresholding-result